# using python how to read only the first line of ping results?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ping

How to read only the first line of ping results using python? On reading ping results with python returns multiple lines. So I like to know how to read and save just the 1st line of output? The code should not only work for ping but should work for tools like "ifstat" too, which again returns multiple line results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command using subprocess.check_output, and return the first of splitlines():

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c1', '192.168.0.1']).splitlines()[0]
```

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and [`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). Here [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) runs the command and returns the output in a string, and the you can get the first line using `str.splitlines()[0]`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out = subprocess.check_output('ping google.com -c 1', shell=True)
>>> out.splitlines()[0]
'PING google.com (173.194.36.78) 56(84) bytes of data.'
```

Note that running a untrusted command with `shell=True` can be dangerous. So, a better  way would be:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> command = shlex.split('ping google.com -c 1')
>>> out = subprocess.check_output(command)
>>> out.splitlines()[0]
'PING google.com (173.194.36.65) 56(84) bytes of data.'
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you have got output in str variable ping_result, do split and access first in the array http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split. Something like this:

first_line = ping_result.split('\n')[0]